# How to make a dictionary from this data?

Tags: python, dictionary

So the part of my data.dat looks like this:

```
carine        mite, tick
accipitrine   bird: hawk, falcon, or bird of prey
acipenserine  sturgeon
aedine        mosquito (genus Aedes)
alaudine      bird: skylark
alcelaphine   antelopes
alcidine      bird: auk, puffin, or murre
alectorine    crane
anatine       duck, mallard
anguilline    snake
```

How could I create a dictionary that would map multiple values (e.g bird: hawk, falcon, or bird of prey maps to accipitrine) to single keys?

This is my code so far:

```
with open ('collateralAdjectives.dat', 'r') as a:
    adjectives = a.read().splitlines()

d = dict()
for item in collateralAdjectives:
    (s, c) = item.split(' ')
    d[s] = c
```

This is the error that I get:

```
(s, c) = item.split(' ')

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Sounds like you could encode those values to integers. A dictionary may store such encoding easily.

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question with the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I am new to Python. So how can I extract only the values from the second column?

Comment: what is exactly your expected output ?

Comment: What should be in dictionary `d2` after processing your sample data? Please [edit] your question again and add it. Also, what's in the `collateralAdjectives` variable?

Comment: My expected outcome is to have the left column as a keys and right one as values to those keys.

collateralAdjectives.dat contains the whole data which part of have written above. d2 meant to be a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

To map a single key to multiple values, instead map that key to a list containing those values.

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary['carine'] = ['mite','tick']
...
dictionary['anguilline'] = ['snake']
```

Comment: would you mind expanding your answer a bit? Perhaps showing what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines does the job on this example; must be tuned for biggest set.
I use `pandas` for its excellent readers. Then `re` to fine string manipulations.

```
df0=pd.read_fwf('dic.dat',colspecs=[(0,14),(14,50)],index_col=0, header=None)
df = df0.applymap(lambda s : re.split(', or |, ',s.split(': ')[-1]))

carine                        [mite, tick]
accipitrine   [hawk, falcon, bird of prey]
acipenserine                    [sturgeon]
aedine            [mosquito (genus Aedes)]
alaudine                         [skylark]
alcelaphine                    [antelopes]
alcidine              [auk, puffin, murre]
alectorine                         [crane]
anatine                    [duck, mallard]
anguilline                         [snake]
```

You can then make a dict by `d=df[1].to_dict()` :

```
{'accipitrine': ['hawk', 'falcon', 'bird of prey'],
 'acipenserine': ['sturgeon'],
 'aedine': ['mosquito (genus Aedes)'],
 'alaudine': ['skylark'],
 'alcelaphine': ['antelopes'],
 'alcidine': ['auk', 'puffin', 'murre'],
 'alectorine': ['crane'],
 'anatine': ['duck', 'mallard'],
 'anguilline': ['snake'],
 'carine': ['mite', 'tick']}
```

or use the df as is : `df.loc['carine']` is `['mite', 'tick']`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
import io

s = """\
carine        mite, tick
accipitrine   bird: hawk, falcon, or bird of prey
acipenserine  sturgeon
aedine        mosquito (genus Aedes)
alaudine      bird: skylark
alcelaphine   antelopes
alcidine      bird: auk, puffin, or murre
alectorine    crane
anatine       duck, mallard
anguilline    snake"""
```

Can do like this:

```
{i.split(' ')[0]:' '.join((i.strip() for i in i.split(' ')[1:] if i)) for i in io.StringIO(s)}
```

Output:

```
{'accipitrine': 'bird: hawk, falcon, or bird of prey',
 'acipenserine': 'sturgeon',
 'aedine': 'mosquito (genus Aedes)',
 'alaudine': 'bird: skylark',
 'alcelaphine': 'antelopes',
 'alcidine': 'bird: auk, puffin, or murre',
 'alectorine': 'crane',
 'anatine': 'duck, mallard',
 'anguilline': 'snake',
 'carine': 'mite, tick'}
```